# PHP warnings cause script to halt on IIS running FastCGI

Tags: php, iis-6, windows-server-2003, fastcgi

We are migrating to a new server running Windows 2003 and IIS 6. When my PHP code runs, it has a warning on a particular line (which I'm expecting at the moment but will fix shortly). However, when it hits the warning, it immediately halts processing and returns a 500 error in the HTTP header. Normally, I would expect PHP to output the warning, but continue processing the script.

Is there something in the configuration for IIS, FastCGI, or PHP that would be returning 500 errors when PHP hits a warning?

**To clarify:** I don't want to suppress the warnings; I want them to display. I do not want the script to stop processing on warnings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured out the issue. `log_errors` in php.ini was set to `On`, but `error_log` was unset. This was causing PHP to stop everything. After setting `display_errors` to `on`, the warnings now display so I can see where things are breaking in the output.

This thread was helpful: http://forums.iis.net/p/1146102/1856222.aspx#1856222

Comment: So, what do you set `error_log` to? Please include that in your answer to help others.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen you can set error_log = syslog

Comment: anyone coming from Google. You just have to uncomment the error_log line in the php.init. for Windows it defaults to syslog which log the errors to the event log.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about IIS or FastCGI, but afaik php has no such option. You can however set `error_reporting` (in your `php.ini`) to

```
E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR
```

to make warnings go away.

Answer (score 0):

That depends very much on your PHP code as well, if you are doing something complicated within the code and an error occurs, web servers sometimes throw 500 errors. I would suggest you:

1. Put an `@` on the line to suppress the error, i.e :

   $x=@my_function($y);
2. See your web server logs for the exact error message you get, then post it here and perhaps we could offer you a better solution.